# MySQL - Date Format

Tags: mysql

A couple of questions.

In SQL Developer I could type `alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YY HH:24:MI:SS';` to include the time and all queries on that tab would then include this format. I could then type `alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YY';` to remove the time. Any easy equivalent in MySQL that could flip my date formats like this?

If it's not that simple, let me ask this: Can the format be changed on a single query line. So if i have this

`select name, start_date from Users;`

If this normally shows the date and time, how can i alter it to only have the results show just the date?

Answer (score 1):

> Any easy equivalent in MySQL that could flip my date formats like this?

Yes, there is.
What you're looking for is the `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

Example:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(start_date,'%d-%m-%Y') from Users
```

Adjust the specifiers as needed.
Common specifiers:

```
%d   day of month
%m   month
%Y   year
%H   hour (00..23)
%h   hour (01..12)
%p   AM or PM
%i   minutes
%s   seconds
```

For other specifiers, see [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: That was awesome info man thanks.  I've never used this site before but if it's gonna be this cool to use i may bug y'all all the time lol.  Nah but i actually looked around online for a while but everything seemed unclear in how it was reading.  Your answer was perfect.

Last question on this subject.   Is there any way to set that date format so that all queries ran on that tab will keep that format or does the date_format set up need to be configured for each query?

Comment: @sean Unfortunately, it is hard coded to %Y-%m-%d. So, you have to call date_format() in every query.

Comment: Roger that sir.  No problem there, thanks  a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

`start_date` is presumably a `datetime` column. You can truncate the time by converting it to a  `date`:

```
SELECT name, DATE(start_date)
FROM   users
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.  The other comment gave one way and this is another.  Both are perfect for me to keep track of as i'll be using both at various times.

As i asked the other person for their method, is there a way to configure MySQL to where it'll show all the datetime columns with the DATE format or does one have to type DATE(start_date) for each and every query?   If so it's no big deal, just wondering if that was a capability in MySQL just as it is in SQL Developer's 'alter session' feature, thanks.

Comment: @sean As you noted, `alter session` is an Oracle syntax. I'm not aware of a MySQL equivilant.

Comment: Ok fair enough.  As long as i know how to make it happen for a given query i'm good to go thanks !